# Kubernetes Job: exactly one pod

Tags: parallel-processing, kubernetes

I want to run only one pod of my kubernetes app at a time(relaunch in case of failure), I am using [job controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/).

But as per documentations, kubernetes may launch more than one pods and will eventually achieve specified replicas. Is there any way to achieve exactly one pod at a time or any recommended design pattern for such use cases.

My app is reading data from HDFS and writing it to a message queue. It exits after processing all the files. I want to minimize possibility of writing duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use replicasets for this. Set the number of replica to 1. More here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/#when-to-use-a-replicaset

Comment: Thanks but as far as I know replicaset has the same problem. Kubernetes may launch more than specified replicas. Also I don't think replicaset is a recommended controller for Run to Completion usecases.

Comment: Do you mean that you would want pods to terminate on completion ?

Comment: Now this is an interesting read. Jump to Handling Pod and Container Failures on https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/

Comment: Thanks Mayur. "even if you specify .spec.parallelism = 1 and .spec.completions = 1 and .spec.template.spec.restartPolicy = "Never", the same program may sometimes be started twice.", so there is no guarantee that only one instance will be launched. I believe there must be some recommended design pattern to handle such scenarios

Answer (score 0):

In principle, in the case of Jobs with no paralellism implied, there shouldn't be this kind of "race condition" ("should be 1" according to the documentation [1]). The job would be rescheduled only if an attempt fails. Did you come across the situation where 2 pods from the same job were being executed at the same time?

In any case, if you want to be completely sure, you may want to implement an extra coordination method or external solution.

---

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/

Comment: Thanks Javier, from the docs: "even if you specify .spec.parallelism = 1 and .spec.completions = 1 and .spec.template.spec.restartPolicy = "Never", the same program may sometimes be started twice." , so there is no guarantee. I believe there must be some recommended design pattern to handle such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly I think you are looking for: .spec.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxSurge

If you set this to 0 then the existing pods will be killed before starting an new one.

Comment: Thanks Milo, I don't need rolling updates. Basically I want to launch kubernetes app(run to completion) every hour using external scheduler. I don't want to run more than 1 pod at a time to avoid duplicate records processing. So, my question is how can I achieve exactly once semantics.

Comment: I think the maxSurge setting is not only for updates. Might be worth to check... But how :)